# Simply set width with CSS or perchance jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BUadD/

I would like simply set witdh for input. For all input in first columns i would like for example 30px, for second 50px, for third 20px and for last 40 px.
Is possible this with CSS or jQuery for all? I must add this for each input?

Comment: You could use the `nth-child` CSS selector for this, however it won't work in <IE9. Alternatively you could put a class on each `input` - if the table is dynamically generated that's probably easiest. Javascript should always be a last resort for UI layout concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS below will make the first column of inputs 30px wide, the second 50px, the third 20px and the last 40px. As noted by Rory, selectors do not work as expected in all browsrs *cough IE*.

```
td:first-child input[type="text"] {
    width: 30px;
}
td:nth-child(2) input[type="text"] {
    width: 50px;
}
td:nth-child(3) input[type="text"] {
    width: 20px;
}
td:last-child input[type="text"] {
    width: 40px;
}
```

​
With jQuery, you could emulate this anyway, see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BUadD/2/

```
$('td:first-child input[type="text"]').css('width', '30px');
$('td:nth-child(2) input[type="text"]').css('width', '50px');
$('td:nth-child(3) input[type="text"]').css('width', '20px');
$('td:last-child input[type="text"]').css('width', '40px');
```

And it worked in IE9 for me.

Answer (score 1):

just add `class="classname"` to the input like so:

```
<input class="left_col" type="text">
```

Then add this to your css:

```
input.left_col {
    width: 30px;
}
```

you can make this for all columns that you want, just remember to give them different names.

Comment: well if you want to change the entire column you will only have to change it once. So eventually this is easier than adding it to each input seperately

Answer (score 1):

Most manipulators work for all fields

```
$("table input[type=text]").css("width", "30px");
```

will set width for all input fields.
To work with last or first fields, use :first or :last selectors:

```
$("input[type=text]:last").css("width", "30px");
```

If you want to set custom width for each field, much better to set "input id", or "input name", to simplify operations:

```
$("#id1").css("width", "30px");
$("#id2").css("width", "20px");
```

Foreach loop isn't good choise for you example, if you have an algorithm for size, for example 
size*2 for each field, than you can use it

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of setting an ID for each field though, I'd avoid applying the CSS for each through jQuery and just put it in a CSS file instead.